# How can I fix the 'stream terminated by RST_STREAM' error when building a Docker image for a Vue app?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm trying to build a new image with docker, but when I enter the build command:
`docker image build -t vue-app .`

I get this error:

```
[+] Building 0.2s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 229B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                     0.2s
 => => transferring context: 67B                                                                                      0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: Internal: Internal: stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Also my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I would be grateful if you can help me.

I tried:
- restarting my machine;
- creating a .dockerignore file;
- changing ports;

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 11 with a fresh install of Docker & WSL2. I tried building both from the windows terminal and the WSL command line.

Answer (score 6):

This issue has to do with the "Dockerfile" text encoding, change it to UTF-8, you can do that in notepad++ or any other editor like VS Code. This fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: this also worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried to build a Dockerfile in the users root folder, the problem was solved by simply moving the folder to the desktop, try it, plus I read that git can somehow interfere

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is still a useful clue, even if not the full solution

Answer (score 0):

Changing the encoding Dockerfile to utf8 should help you solve the problem.